# Interaction with Aave V3 contract getUserAccountData

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

I'm trying to make a normal request to another contract from mine.

```js
    function getUserAccountData(address _miskin) internal view returns (AaveUserData memory) {
        ILendingPool lendingPool = ILendingPool(aaveLendingPoolAddress);
        (uint256 totalCollateralETH, uint256 totalDebtETH, uint256 availableBorrowsETH, uint256 currentLiquidationThreshold, uint256 ltv, uint256 healthFactor) = lendingPool.getUserAccountData(_miskin);
        return AaveUserData(totalCollateralETH, totalDebtETH, availableBorrowsETH, currentLiquidationThreshold, ltv, healthFactor);
    }
```

This is pretty basic and on the line `lendingPool.getUserAccountData(_miskin);`  I get an error: `function returned an unexpected amount of data`.
I don't understand why I have the correct contract address also.
This is my interface

```js
interface ILendingPool {
    function getUserAccountData(address user)
        external
        view
        returns (
            uint256 totalCollateralETH,
            uint256 totalDebtETH,
            uint256 availableBorrowsETH,
            uint256 currentLiquidationThreshold,
            uint256 ltv,
            uint256 healthFactor
        );
}
```

I someone have any idea what can I do I would love thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A struct is decoded differently than the list of its arguments. In particular it has extra bytes at the beginning.

So your code is expecting a output like `(uint256, ..., uint256)` but getting a `AaveUserData` struct. I'm not sure how the output of your internal function `getUserAccountData` is used, but I guess you're reading it using the Aave `ILendingPool` interface, which doesn't return a `AaveUserData` struct.

Comment: Good response that was not the problem but could be. This question lack of information .

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a dum answer but I forked the wrong network so whe.  I tried to call the address with the good polygon address I got an error. So the solution: Fork the good network.